# Is there a method to parse a unique time format in Excel to seconds/minutes/hours/days for duration calculations?

Tags: excel, formula

I want to parse a variable custom time string in Excel using the format:

- value Month (M) (removed : is variable)
- value Weeks (w)
- value Days (d)
- value Hours (h)
- value Minutes (m)
- value Seconds (s)

In a single excel cell it looks like this:

**"3w4d7h2m8s"**
(3 weeks / 4 days / 7 hours / 2 minutes / 8 seconds)

(or any legal variable length string of the above):

"1w3d8s" (1 week / 3 days / 8 seconds)

or

"8s"

and calculate the seconds total of the string (to calculate duration difference in seconds for analysis) to be put in another cell

Any ideas welcome. Thanks :)

Comment: How is this even possible if you don't know which months are used? Wouldn't it be an educated guess more than an accurate amount of seconds?

Comment: You can only determine a month duration with a known start / end date. Seconds(Feb) <> Seconds(July)

Comment: You will have to make an assumption about the number of days in a month, for your example. Then it's just a matter of extracting the appropriate values, either with complicated formulas or, with a VBA UDF, possibly using Regular Expressions.  If that is not OK, you'll need to derive a start and end time (which includes the full date.  Then just subtract one from the other and multiply by 86,400 (the number of seconds in a day).

Comment: Thank you all. Of course. Doh. Is there any solution if we remove months and work with fixed weeks?

Comment: Sure, just parse out the different values and sum the appropriate multiplications to get the number of seconds

Answer (score 0):

Here's a worksheet formula. It assumes your custom time string is in cell `A3`.

```
=604800*IFERROR(INT(MID(A3,1,FIND("w",A3,1)-1)),0)
+ 86400*INT(MID(A3,IFERROR(FIND("w",A3,1),0)+1,FIND("d",A3,1)-IFERROR(FIND("w",A3,1),0)-1))
+  3600*INT(MID(A3,IFERROR(FIND("d",A3,1),0)+1,FIND("h",A3,1)-IFERROR(FIND("d",A3,1),0)-1))
+    60*INT(MID(A3,IFERROR(FIND("h",A3,1),0)+1,FIND("m",A3,1)-IFERROR(FIND("h",A3,1),0)-1))
+       INT(MID(A3,IFERROR(FIND("m",A3,1),0)+1,FIND("s",A3,1)-IFERROR(FIND("m",A3,1),0)-1))
```

The formula assumes that the "w" part is optional, but "d", "h", "m", and "s" all occur in the custom time string.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you xidgel! That works wonderfully :) Thank you again :)